# Correct file path with folders

Tags: python, json, file, path

I created a translating script that searches for a file, for example `bot.json` in this folder structure from the executed file: `data/lang/en/`. I use the following code to do it:

```py
with open(r'data/lang/' + functions.json_module.get_config('Config')['Language'] + r'/bot.json', 'r') as f:
     return json.load(f)['Bot']['starting']
```

`functions.json_module.get_config('Config')['Language']` will return `en`.
What am I doing wrong?

I tried it with '\data\lang...' too but this didn't work either. I was expecting to get the translation for `starting` (`Starting...`).

Comment: Why do you think you're doing something wrong? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Better to use `os.path.join()` or the `PathLib` library, rather than string concatenation.

Comment: Does it work if you hard-code the language instead of using `functions.json_module.get_config('Config')['Language']`?

Comment: Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page. I think your title can be improved.

Comment: It works now, I'm using a normal string with `data\\lang\\en\\bot.json`